# How to stop an user from creating more than one profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

In my `app` I have two models **USER** and **PROFILE**, I want every user to have only one profile, I tried `has_one :profile` association but it's doesn't seems to work the way I want.

*My user model*

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

*My Profile Model*

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: In which way do you want ??

Comment: yo can disable the Profile create form if the user already have a Profile or you can check if exist a user Profile befor create the Profile.

Comment: How do your users create an profile? If it goes trough a form, I would disable or not showing the form if the user already has one profile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're saving profile information, but you could do something like this in your profile `create` controller method (note, I didn't test this but should work):

```
def create
  @profile = user.profile || user.build_profile

  if @profile.update(profile_params)
    # success
  else
    # fail
  end
end
```

The above will update the existing profile if the user has one and will otherwise build a new one.